# How do I iterate through folders before the wanted document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, directory, glob

I am trying to code a script that will collect values from a .xvg files. I have 20 folders that contain the targeted file. Folder are numerated from 1-20 (in the code you see 1.Rimo)

I have already made the code that collects the data when I specify full path, however, I need something generic so I can loop through those 20 folders, get that data and store it as a variable.

```
rmsf = open('/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.ProductionRun/1.Rimo/rmsf.xvg','r+')

for line in rmsf:   
    if line.startswith(' 4755'):
        print (line)
        l = line.split()
        print (l)       
        value = float(l[1])
        sum1 = float(sum1) + value
        print(len(l))
        print (sum1)
```

Comment: You can use `os.listdir` to get a list of contents of a folder. in your case, use it like this: `os.listdir('/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.ProductionRun')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding glob.

```
for name in glob.glob('/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.ProductionRun/*/rmsf.xvg'):

    for line in open(name):
        if line.startswith(' 4755'):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
base_path = '/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.ProductionRun'
file_name = 'rmsf.xvg'

for dir_name in os.listdir(base_path):
    print(dir_name)
    with open(os.path.join(base_path, dir_name, file_name)) as f:
        for line in f:
            # here goes your code
            pass
```

Just remember to join the `dir_name` with the `base_path` (the path of the directory you are iterating over).

Also note that this returns files as well, not just directories. If you folder `/home/alispahic/1.CB1_project/12.ProductionRun` contains only directories, then that won't be a problem; otherwise you would need to filter out the files.